# Unity somehow integrated my google calendar. Would like to know how

Tags: unity, calendar

So recently I've started using google calendar as I like the event notifications etc. I also started using Thunderbird and downloaded an extension which allowed me to open google calendar in a separate tab. I was also looking for a way to integrate google calendar into unity (so I would get notifications for events). When I gave up on this, it turned out that I had managed it somehow (see screenshot). I now get event notifications as well as a list of events below the unity calendar.

I don't know how I did this, but if someone knows how to do this, it would be helpful to know for the purposes of turning it on/off in the future. Perhaps it's Thunderbird's integration with unity? Or is my gmail account somehow connected with my unity sign-in?

[image: unity calendar showing google calendar events screenshot]

Comment: Do you have google setup as one of your online accounts in the system settings?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I think you solved it. That's weird though because I can't remember setting it up like that ... ymaybe it took my username/password which I let firefox remember? Anyways, I now know how to do it in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I switched to Gnome from Unity to try it out, connected to a Google online account there, and switched back to Unity. In Unity I could not see the Google account under online accounts but it's calendars showed nevertheless in the default calendar app and in the time/date on top.

Except deleting the account in Gnome, I don't really saw a solution.